# Reading the input and checking if it ends with two newlines

Tags: c++, file, loops, stream

I am writing a program in which the message is complete if the user presses the return key twice. And the way to check (as prescribed) is by checking to see if two consecutive `'\n'` occurrences have been read. I am confused as how to do this. Studying this thread at: [How do I store a previous iteration in a while loop in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468373/how-do-i-store-a-previous-iteration-in-a-while-loop-in-c)

I got some idea and did this:

```
for(new_advice; getline(cin, new_advice);) {
    if(new_advice.substr(new_advice.length()-2,2).compare("\n\n") == 0) {
        outstream<<endl;
        outstream<<advice;
    }
}
```

I got one error and a warning.
The error is:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

And the warning is

> expression result unused (The expression is new_advice)

What should I do? Files and streams are a bit confusing (I am new to C++)
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The warning for your `new_advice` initial expression in the `for` statement. Simply drop it, so the `for` is `for (; getline(...); )`

Comment: or use a `while` loop :)

Comment: Could you help me use a while loop in this?

Comment: `while(getline(...))` instead of `for(; getline(...); )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getline` reads a line from the given stream and stores it in the variable given in the second parameter. It *overwrites* the contents of the given variable. Furthermore, it does *not* put the newline character into the variable. That means, you don't find two newline characters in the string, not even a single one.

When the user hits the return key twice, two lines are read by your C++ application, of which the second is empty.

You should detect that case by checking if the read line is empty. If this is the case, that means the user just hit the return key for the second time, and the *previously* read string was his actual input. That means that you need to store the input in a different string variable such that `getline` doesn't overwrite your variable.

Something like this:

```
string new_advice;
string input;

while (getline(cin, input)) {
    if (input.empty()) {
        // Do something with new_advice
    }
    else {
        // Remember input for the case where the user hits return key again
        new_advice = input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (std::string new_advice; std::getline(std::cin, new_advice);)
{
    if ('\n' == std::cin.peek()) {
        // Two consecutive new line characters. Do something with new_advice.

        std::cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong. It did remove the warning and the error but created no results. I did this:

    **bold**for (std::string new_advice; std::getline(std::cin, new_advice);)
        {
            if ('\n' == std::cin.peek()) {
                outstream<<endl;
                outstream<<new_advice;
            }
        }**bold**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A basic test works for me. See [here](http://ideone.com/XEpg8G). Notice that only the first line is printed because its the only one followed by two new lines.

Comment: Please don't post "code-only" answers. Instead, explain your code and why you're offering it as an answer.

Comment: @Simple It works but after 3 new line characters and I want it to terminate after 2 new line characters.. So

**This is an advice.\n\n** _terminate_

Comment: @G.K. then either `return` from the function or call `exit` inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

How about using e.g. [`std::string::rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind)?

```
if (new_advice.rfind("\n\n") == new_advice.size() - 2)
{
    // Last two characters were newlines
}
```

Comment: We haven't been taught rfind. So I doubt we will be allowed to use it. :(

Comment: @G.K. Unless you were told to specifically use some specific function, I don't see why you can't use the complete toolset that is available to you?